# guava eventbus with qualifier

Tags: spring, event-handling, guava, qualifiers

I want to use the guava eventBus in a spring application. I am wandering if (and how) it is possible to use qualifiers for the events like I would do with CDI @Observes. Is there any documentation on this or maybe a 3rd party framework I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I believe guava approach to distinguish events, is by event type - your @Subscriber will receive events only if they are of specified type or part of inheritance hierarchy from this type.

Here are some useful links:

- https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as well ... I was looking for a "maybe this works with framework guava-magic-3.1-beta7" solution ... will check the reactor approach, could be the thing I was really looking for.